# Chrome hides content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have sidemenu bar , in chrome when mouseover it , open dropdown and scroll multi times , chrome discard all content
[website link](http://bakhabarsho.ir)

before : 
[image]

after : 
[image]

it just happen in chrome , what is problem ?

Comment: this is because of the direction: rtl

Comment: why ? how i fix this ?